# MSAL Java Servlet Example: How to avoid Sign-In button prompting "Pick an account"?

Tags: java, azure, authentication, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

I installed the MSAL Java Servlet example. It basically works, however when I click on the "Sign In" button it sends me to https://login.microsoftonline.com to present a prompt "Pick an account" (only 1 account listed). I can select my account manually and then it let's me into the MSAL sample app "You are signed in" page. (I should also note, that for the first time after clicking the account, it sends me to a MFA page, but not subsequent logins)

QUESTION: How can I configure it to not prompt me to pick my account since there is only 1 account? (And avoid the MFA page?)

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/tree/main/3.%20Java%20Servlet%20Web%20App%20Tutorial/1-Authentication/sign-in

I expected to click on "sign in" and for it to authenticate and redirect to main app index page. Instead, it asks me to select which windows account, and then if the first time, will also issue a MFA page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your problem and found a fix which will not let the prompt to choose the account again and again.
I found that in your **AuthHelper** class there is a method called **redirectToAuthorizationEndpoint**.
and the configuration for **AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters** as

```java
AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters  parameters  =  AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters.builder(Config.REDIRECT_URI, Collections.singleton(Config.SCOPES)).responseMode(ResponseMode.QUERY)
.prompt(Prompt.SELECT_ACCOUNT).state(state).nonce(nonce).build();
```

I have reproduced with the same configuration and I was getting the prompt repeatedly to choose the account to signin.
[image]

When I sign in below, it was redirecting to the prompt to choose the account as shown below:.
[image]

[image]

Prompt method allow to choose the account even if you have only one account.

**Fix:**

To avoid this issue, we have to just remove the whole prompt method and configure like below:

```java
AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters  parameters  =  AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters.builder(Config.REDIRECT_URI,  Collections.singleton(Config.SCOPES)).responseMode(ResponseMode.QUERY)
.state(state).nonce(nonce).build();
```

[image]

In this case, even If u have only one account to login, it will not redirect to choose account blade.
When I click on signin, it is not redirecting to the prompt to choose account as I have already signed in with my account once:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! However, after removing the prompt method, I am still getting the browser prompt and MFA (?) Was there something else you did?

Comment: 22-Mar-2023 10:19:50.372 INFO com.microsoft.azuresamples.msal4j.helpers.AuthHelper.signIn sign in init
22-Mar-2023 10:19:50.373 INFO com.microsoft.azuresamples.msal4j.helpers.AuthHelper.authorize preparing to authorize
22-Mar-2023 10:19:50.373 INFO com.microsoft.azuresamples.msal4j.helpers.AuthHelper.authorize did not find auth result in session. trying to interactively acquire token...

Comment: Try creating your app using the command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment --name my-sp --password my-password --skip-mfa`. It gives the option to skip MFA.

Comment: @kenedward, let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: My Admin reviewing above command. Mean time, I try to build with 
 AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters parameters = AuthorizationRequestUrlParameters
                .builder(Config.REDIRECT_URI, Collections.singleton(Config.SCOPES)).responseMode(ResponseMode.QUERY)
                .prompt(Prompt.NONE).state(state).nonce(nonce).build();
It complains
[ERROR] in/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azuresamples/msal4j/helpers/AuthHelper.java:[122,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable NONE

https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j/1.13.7/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j/Prompt.html

Comment: using the above, and setting supported account types to our ORG only instead of multitenant , and  using loginhint and domainhint solved the issue